# When to use multiple main methods?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, netty

I am confused when it is proper to use an application with multiple entry points, or I guess an application with multiple interconnected modules. I have a network application (Netty) as well as a web application (spring). I can bundle them together, in effect tightly coupling them together, or I can modularize them to operate interdependently of each other while still working together to make the application whole.

Is there any specific reason for making an application a single entity vs multiple entities? Is it "desired" to have a self contained application (eg. One main method)?

Comment: You're probably overthinking this.  Modularization doesn't have anything to do with multiple main methods; you call main once, and then your application calls library functions (which don't have main methods).

Comment: The thing is I was looking at some examples of using RabbitMQ and they had the publisher/receiver running in two different applications. And since I plan on using that to communicate between both components I thought I would have to split my application up the same way.

Comment: @DiljotR An application can be modular but still deployed as one artifact. Deploying them as two separate processes offers no extra advantage in that respect.

Comment: Muthithreading? Multiple Routes listening to two components as in the case of using Apache Camel?

Comment: @prash That's a third aspect, yes.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, asking about the number of `main()` methods is a bit misleading. You can have several classes with `main()` methods in a single JAR file after all.

But the question seems to be more about single application vs. multiple applications, or to be more precise: [tiers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-tier_architecture).

It's important to note that this issue is separate from the question of modularity and multi-threading, all of which can be employed in a single tier application just as easily as in a multi-tier application.

The reasons you'd need a multi-tiered application can vary, but here are a few examples:

1. **It is simply part of the requirements:** i.e. a chat software will usually need a server and a client because the requirement is to move data between two computers.
2. **Scaling:** you need to spread the work to multiple computers to cope with large amounts of data or requests. (This is a typical use case of message queues for example.)
3. **Separation of concerns:** This typically happens in "enterprise" systems, where different functions need to be performed in complete isolation, allowing modules to be replaced/restarted on the go or to scale them separately.

Answer (score 0):

Web applications are supposed to have multiple entries; think of the URL you type that can lead to to a resource. In fact, in many web application architectures, such as JAX-RS, exposing the resource URI is encouraged. Each entity, as small as one java bean, has its own entry point. Not sure if this is what you mean, but that's my opinion.